# How to compute Binomial Distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

**A basketball player scores a point in a free throw with 80% probability. Probability is independent of the result of the previous throw.**

**1) Given 5 free throws, find the probability distribution of the number of points scored by the player, and illustrate it by a histogram.**

(I was thinking of fx(t) for t= 0, 1 with X~Bin(5, 0.8), but don't know how to compute to abtain the result! 
And simply have no idea how to generate the histogram! Do I computer the possibility for each of the 5 free throws? or possibility for the score 0 and 1? Have no idea how to get the individual possibility :'( )

**2) What’s the probability that the player scores more than 200 points in free throws during the season?**

(was thinking of P(X ≥ 200) but again don't know how to compute :'( )

**3) During a season, the player performs 100 free throws. What’s the expected value of points scored in free throws during the season?**

(am I right to compute as E(X) = np = 100*0.8 = 80? )

**4) During a season, what’s the variance of the points scored in free throws?**

(am I right to compute as Var(X) = np(1-p) = 100*0.8*(1-0.8) = 100*0.8*0.2 = 16? The result looks a bit awkward...)

Sorry for the dumb questions, I'm a novice to such problems and thus quite confused. Much appreciated for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

**If** the random variable has a **[Binomial Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)**, that is it measures the successes in a series of Bernoulii trials, then the probability of obtaining some *arrangement* of $x$ successes and $n-x$ failures is given by:

$$X\sim \mathcal{Bin}(n, p) \;\iff\; \mathsf P(X=x) \,=\, \begin{cases}\dbinom{n}{x} p^x(1-p)^{n-x} &:x\in\{0\ldots n\}\\[1ex]0& : \text{else}\end{cases}$$

Use this to generate a histogram of $X\sim\mathcal{Bin}(5, 0.8)$ for $x$ in $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$.

$$\text{Plot}\quad \mathsf P(X=x) \,=\, \dbinom{5}{x} 0.8^x\,0.2^{5-x} \quad\text{for}\quad x\in\{0\ldots 5\}$$

---

For large numbers of trials we typically use an approximation, such as the Normal approximation, or the Poisson approximation.   For this case I suggest normal approximation.

$$\mathcal{Bin}(n, p) \;\dot\sim\; \mathcal{N}(np, np(1-p))$$

Then use the Normal Tables (or an online calculator) to look up the relevant probabilities.

However you cannot compute, or even approximate, the probability of scoring more than 200 points *unless you know the number of free throws* in a season.

( If it is $100$ free throws, as in the follow up questions, the probability of scoring more than $200$ points is simply zero. )

---

For the remaining questions, where you *are* given a number of free throws to use, you have the right answers.  For a Binomial Distribution (or its approximation):

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X) &= np \\ \mathsf{Var}(X) &= np(1-p) \end{align}$$